# onclick-event doesn't work in Firefox - works in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

I've implement an onclick event called: remove(this). It works fine in the Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox. I set a breakpoint on the remove function, so I saw that the IE call this function and the FF doesn't.  *(Debugged with Firebug and IE DeveloperTools)*

**Internet Explorer:**

```
<INPUT onclick="remove( this )" id=NBGTEST-1075_0002__Update__DeleteButton 
title="Remove Spawn" class="update field-button" type=button value=Delete 
name=NBGTEST-1075_0002__Update__SpawnButton>
```

**Firefox:**

```
<input id="NBGTEST-1075_0005__Update__DeleteButton" 
class="update field-button" type="button" onclick="remove( this )" 
value="Delete" title="Remove Spawn" name="NBGTEST-1075_0005__Update__SpawnButton">
```

The input button have the same parameters only the order is different, but this shouldn't be the error.

***This do the program:***
Theres a button A. When button A is clicked, a button B will be generated. Button B can be removed. The function remove()- removes the button again. 
When I press the delete button, the button get hide but the row is still visible. The row will remove in the remove() function

*Code of button A (Add-Button):*

IE:

```
<INPUT onclick="add( this )" id=NBGTEST-1075_Main__Update__SpawnButton 
title="Create Spawn" class="update field-button" type=button value="Add Spawn" 
name=NBGTEST-1075_Main__Update__SpawnButton>
```

FF:

```
<input id="NBGTEST-1075_Main__Update__SpawnButton" class="update field-button" 
type="button" onclick="add( this )" value="Spawn MR" title="Create Spawn" 
name="NBGTEST-1075_Main__Update__SpawnButton">
```

Both browsers fires the add(this) event.

I tested with the IE11 and FF 32.0.3

**Funny Fact: When I create an Internet Explorer Tab in Firefox, then it also works!**

The remove function:

```
function remove( button )
{
    if( isButton( button ) && isUpdateSection( button.id ) )
    {
         //here I remove the button/row
    }
  return( false );
}
```

Comment: The code also worked on earlier Firefox versions.

Comment: Can you show the `add(this)` and `remove(this)` js functions?

Comment: The code of these functions are quite long. But the problem is, that the function is not called in firefox

Comment: Put up a `jsFiddle` for us to see the issue.

Comment: Its difficult, because only the javascript code has more than 5000 lines of code. I tried to abstract the problem as far as possible.

Comment: You've abstracted it out too far though. You have to provide a reproducible problem or nobody can help you debug it.

Comment: sry guys, its pretty hard to explain. I am very grateful for your help. I've read that the IE uses JScript and Firefox uses Javascript. So this are different versions. Could there be any problems with that? Because it worked on older firefox versions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I just changed the function name from remove() in removes(). Presumably, remove() is an internal javascript function and firefox use that function. Instead Internet Explorer detects that I defined my own remove() function.